# Copying specific column from one workbook to another after comparing with another

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel files. Among many columns in both these files, they have a column with a filename and a column with comments.

What I want is to read the comments against the filename from file A, then search for the same filename in file B, and copy the same comments there.

Is there an easy way to do this? Through some Linux commands maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be done with a `VLOOKUP` like so:

In each of your rows in file B/column B, place this formula, changing the range/sheet references to the appropriate values: `=VLOOKUP(A1,[FileA]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

For example:

File B, Sheet1, Row 2, Column B (looking in File A, Sheet1) formula = `=VLOOKUP(A2,[FileA]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

File B, Sheet1, Row 3, Column B (looking in File A, Sheet2) formula = `=VLOOKUP(A3,[FileA]Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

**If you have lots of data, this can be slow to calculate.*